# How do you set the lifetime of a Rust trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I can set the lifetime for a Waypoint in the struct Route. In the struct AMoreDifferentRoute I use the trait Coord and get the error

> explicit lifetime bound required

How do you set the lifetime of a trait in this case?

```
extern crate collections;
use super::wp;
use coord::Coord;


pub struct Route<'a> {
    waypoints: &'a Vec<wp::Waypoint>
}

pub struct AMoreDifferentRoute<'a> {
    waypoints: &'a Vec<Coord>
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You write it as an additional trait bound:

```
pub struct AMoreDifferentRoute<'a> {   // '
    waypoints: &'a Vec<Box<Coord+'a>>
}
```

You need to specify a lifetime in `Box<Coord+'a>` because the trait can be implemented for a struct which has a lifetime parameter itself, so there should be a way to specify this lifetime parameter even if the actual struct type is hidden behind a trait object.

Moreover, you can't have bare `Coord` as its size is unknown, because `Vec` needs to know its components size to lay them out in memory properly. Hence you need some kind of wrapper to store trait objects. `Box` will do nicely.

Comment: I'm getting an error that [core::kinds::Sized](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/kinds/trait.Sized.html) is not implemented by coord::Coord+'a and that is required by [collections::vec::Vec](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html). e.g. `waypoints: &'a Vec<Coord+ 'a>`

Comment: Sorry, of course there will be an error. I should have mentioned that it won't work without `Box` wrapper because bare trait types are unsized and can't be stored in `Vec`.

Comment: Could you please explain what the `Coord+ 'a` syntax mean?

Comment: @NicolasBonnefon, well, it is explained in the text. This is "a way to specify this lifetime even if the struct type is hidden behind a trait object".

Comment: @NicolasBonnefon, I've rewritten the answer slightly, maybe it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

As `Coord` is a trait, you need to box the value in some way as a *trait object*, such as `Vec<Box<Coord>>`.

You should also strongly consider whether this is actually what you want anyway; very often it’s not. But to make any sort of judgement on that, I’d need to see more code.

Comment: I just wanted to have a collection of things that implement lat long. Then I might add functions for calculating total distance etc. I would like order to be deterministic.